java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed when file saved to Room database
I download several files by URL from the network using the okHttp3 library and in the body of the response, receiving a ByteArray (like response.body?.bytes()). Next, I need to save these files as a ByteArray into the room library.
            try {
                val request = okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build()
                val response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()


                fileDao.add(
                    FileDatabaseEntity(
                        domain = url,
                        value = response.body?.bytes() ?: ByteArray(0),
                    )
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                AppLogger.tag(TAG).e("Processing $url| Error: $e")
            }

My database entity looks like:
@Entity(tableName = FILE)
class FileDatabaseEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = ID)
    val id: Long = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = DOMAIN)
    val domain: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = VALUE, typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
    var value: ByteArray,
) {
    companion object {
        const val FILE = "file"
        const val ID = "id"
        const val DOMAIN = "domain"
        const val VALUE = "value"
    }
}

but in this case, when trying to add an object to the database with
    @Insert
    fun add(file: FileDatabaseEntity)

I get an error java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed in catch block for add method.
At the same time, if I specifically specify the value only as ByteArray(0) - it saves a record with an empty value for this field. It also works correctly if I specify a string with a random value as the field type (which indicates that the database as a whole is correctly configured - I can write, read, delete table records).
What is my mistake in saving the ByteArray to the Room table?

I do not know what AppLogger is, but you need to adjust your logging such that you get a full Java stack trace. Also, I do not know if your code will compile, as responce does not seem to be defined -- you have response (ending in se, not ce) elsewhere.

AppLogger - just my implementation of Timber logger. The second case - yes, i'am already fix it. I tried various solutions and rolled them back before writing the question - accidentally there was a typo. I fixed it in the code and will now edit the code in the question, thanks
